# Installing tensorflow on anaconda/mac?

Tags: macos, tensorflow, anaconda

I can not find a solution to install tensorflow on anaconda/mac.

When i try: **conda install tensorflow**,
I get:

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - blaze -> numba -> numpy=1.13
  - tensorflow
Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

I tried reinstalling numpy, and could not find any relevant documentation.

Answer (score 5):

On mac use following command:

```
    conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

This will install the latest Tensorflow on your system. if you wish to upgrade it to newer version then you can use the following command

```
    conda update -f -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had success installing tensorflow through pip...

```
pip install tensorflow
```

or, if you have all of the proper libraries...

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

But if you have already removed numpy form the anaconda install, you might be in for a long day because almost all of the numeric packages require it. If the above pip install doesn't work, you might want to start from a clean anaconda install.

Comment: Many thanks, i succeeded after following instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac, 'Installing with Anaconda'

Comment: Using `pip install tensorflow-gpu` on a mac results in a `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0 pip --no-cache-dir install tensorflow-gpu

Answer (score 0):

I have installed tensorflow using -

> pip install tensorflow

Or, you can use Anaconda in following way -

> 1. Open Anaconda Navigator
> 2. On Left side go to Environments
> 3. Create a new environment (eg :- tensorflow_tf), select python 3.7
> 4. then select Not installed and Search "tensorflow"
> 5. click on tensorflow and apply